# I want to create a join table in Rails that belongs to four or five other tables. Does this seem logically flawed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, join

I'd like to create a join table called "role_assignments," which joins four or five other tables. When I query a single role assignment for a single user, this will in turn  query the other tables for relevant information.

Am I headed down a bad path here? Are there crippling performance issues in store for me? I've never done this before, but going with this sort of join table makes perfect sense to me for my particular situation. Any insights you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad idea. Depends on the details of your situation.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering whether there is some best practice that is axiomatically opposed to what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: I would argue that a thing (`role_assignment`), that needs to know four or five other things (the associations to other tables) to exist and produce usefull answers, has perhaps to many responsibilities and knows perhaps to much. I would be interested why you think that you need to join all these tables. What kind of data do they store, what do you try to achieve?

Comment: They store the user ID, the event ID, the role ID, the event's booth ID. I could probably boil this down to user ID, booth ID, and role ID. Booth ID technically contains knowledge of the event.